# Sample code on how to do ODF document rendering in webodf

Tags: node.js, webodf

I have some old program which we use to auto-generate table/curves etc. This program dumps LaTex.
We are now moving to ODF standard instead of LaTex.

I am look for some examples on how to use webodf to render documents like table, section, reference, table of contents.

I have look at the API for webodf but I don't know where to start.

Can somebody show men some examples in ex. node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WebODF is primarily a client-side, browser-based rendering system. It only has very limited success in node.js as it is very dependent on the browser's DOM model & custom stylesheets in order to render the document output.

I don't really think it's well suited to your use case at this particular point in time, unfortunately.